# Function does not return object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am returning an object in function but it returns `undefined` why? here is my code

```
parseXML = function (xml) {
        return {
            lon  : $(xml).find('GEOCODE').find("LOC").attr('lon'),
            lat  : $(xml).find('GEOCODE').find("LOC").attr('lat'),
            x    : $(xml).find('GEOCODE').find("LOC").attr('x'),
            y    : $(xml).find('GEOCODE').find("LOC").attr('y')
        };
    },

    searchRoute = function () {
        var userloc, dest; 
        userloc = cityattr.init(from, to, fromurl, parseXML);
        //dest    = cityattr.init(from, to, fromurl, parseXML);

        console.log(userloc);
    };
```

**Update**

When I do `console.log()` inside parseXML then it returns correct object

```
parseXML = function (xml) {
        var obj = {
            lon  : $(xml).find('GEOCODE').find("LOC").attr('lon'),
            lat  : $(xml).find('GEOCODE').find("LOC").attr('lat'),
            x    : $(xml).find('GEOCODE').find("LOC").attr('x'),
            y    : $(xml).find('GEOCODE').find("LOC").attr('y')
        };

        console.log(obj);
    },
```

**Update 2**

still return `undefined`

```
parseXML = function (xml) {
        return {
            lon  : $(xml).find('GEOCODE').find("LOC").attr('lon'),
            lat  : $(xml).find('GEOCODE').find("LOC").attr('lat'),
            x    : $(xml).find('GEOCODE').find("LOC").attr('x'),
            y    : $(xml).find('GEOCODE').find("LOC").attr('y')
        };
    },
```

here is code for cityattr

```
var Xml = function () {
var to, from, url, result,

    init = function (fromaddress, toaddress, link, callback) {
        from    = fromaddress;
        to      = toaddress;
        url     = link;

        requestXml(callback);
    },

    requestXml = function (callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            dataType: "xml",
            success: callback
        });
    },

    getResult = function () {
        return result;
    };

 return {
    init        : init,
    getResult   : getResult
 };
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return AJAX response Text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225667/how-to-return-ajax-response-text)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You define the function using a *function expression* (so it isn't hoisted) **after** you pass `parseXML` to `cityattr.init`.

At the time you pass it, it hasn't yet been defined.

Change the order of your code or use a *function declaration*.

Comment: OP probably wants to call the function as well

Comment: Possibly. Without knowing what `cityattr.init` does, it is hard to say. It might be expecting a callback function.

Comment: Well I changed the order but still it returns `undefined`

Comment: Judging from "I am returning an object in function but it returns `undefined`", OP seems to think the function is being called

Comment: @JanDvorak What to do now? I think I am already calling a function which is parseXML

Comment: You aren't returning anything from `parseXML` now.

Comment: `console.log(userloc);` is testing the return value of `cityattr.init` not `parseXML`. You still haven't shared `cityattr.init` with us.

Comment: When I return after changing the order of functions then still it returns undefined but when I do console.log() inside parseXML then it does logs out correct object. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: `console.log(userloc);` is still testing the return value of `cityattr.init` not `parseXML`. You still haven't shared `cityattr.init` with us. Your updated `parseXML` has no `return` statement now so it will always return `undefined`

Comment: `console.log(userloc);` is still testing the return value of **`cityattr.init`** (which we **still** can't see) not `parseXML`.

Comment: @x4f4r — See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225667/how-to-return-ajax-response-text — You're using Ajax, you can't return a value from it.

Comment: Is there any technique for this?

Comment: @x4f4r — See the accepted answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225667/how-to-return-ajax-response-text

Comment: @Quentin can I use $.get() method over here. I mean can I return data from $.get() method? That accepted answer will not fullfil my requirements here.

Comment: Not in any sane way. If you are doing Ajax, then do work on data using a callback, not a return value.