# Properties for an object and this

Tags: javascript

I would like Create an object to store variables which I will use in my web app.

I cannot access the `clientId` and `clientSecret` from `uriGetToken` using `this`.

Also I can use the function in `mApiGetToken` in `token`.

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

        // General Settings
        var mApiSettings = {
            clientId: 'aaa',
            clientSecret: 'bbb',
            token: mApiGetToken(),
            uriGetToken: 'https://ccc/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=' + this.clientId + '&client_secret=' + this.clientSecret
        }

        console.log(mApiSettings.uriGetToken);
        // Get Autheticated, it requires getting a Token from HollyByte
        function mApiGetToken() {

            $.getJSON(mApiSettings.uriGetToken, processData);
            function processData(data) {
                mApiSettings.token = data.access_token;
            }
            //return token;
        }

        // For Testing
        console.log(mApiGetToken());

    });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return AJAX response Text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225667/how-to-return-ajax-response-text)

Comment: sorry but your link it is not related to my question, I have a problem with this in a property

Comment: I just noticed that while the question does answer a problem you have, you haven't encountered that problem yet.

Comment: you don't have to define an extra pair of variables. I have fixed the error from the code in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `this` is determined for the *function in which it appears* when that function is called.

There is no connection between the object literal in which you are using `this` and the value of `this`.

There is also no way to access a property of an object in the middle of the object literal statement that is creating it.

You need to use variables.

Although your examples don't have any special characters in them, you should make it a habit to escape any data you are inserting into a URI.

```
    var clientId, clientSecret, mApiSettings;
    clientId = 'aaa';
    clientSecret = 'bbb';
    mApiSettings = {
        clientId: clientId,
        clientSecret: clientSecret,
        token: mApiGetToken(),
        uriGetToken: 'https://ccc/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=' + encodeURIComponent(clientId) + '&client_secret=' + encodeURIComponent(clientSecret)
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your last edit, may I ask you the reason why do you escape character within the URL? thanks

Comment: Because if the data contains a special character (such as `&`) then it won't be passed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It is a common Javascript question because `this` keyword doesn't behave like other OOP language like Java or C++.

The problem is:

```
var o = {
    a : 2,
    b : this.a *2
}
console.log( b ); //prints NaN because the value for this.a is undefined at the time b is being initialized
```

Because `this` is not accessible inside the object literal initialization. A workaround would be to use the name of the object instead of `this`:

```
var o = {
    a : 2,
    b : o.a *2
}
console.log( b ); //prints 4
```

Or you can define the object one-piece at a time:

```
var o = {
    a : 2
}
o.b = o.a *2;
console.log( b ); //prints 4
```

Anyway your code should work if you change the `mApiSettings` to:

```
var mApiSettings = {
            clientId: 'aaa',
            clientSecret: 'bbb',
            token: mApiGetToken()
}

mApiSettings.uriGetToken = 'https://ccc/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=' + mApiSettings.clientId + '&client_secret=' + mApiSettings.clientSecret;
```

You can read more about the Javascript `this` keyword here: http://unschooled.org/2012/03/understanding-javascript-this/

EDIT:

as the other answer suggests you may want to encode your clientSecret and clientId before embedding them into the URL. If that is the case, you can use this code:

```
var mApiSettings = {
            clientId: 'aaa',
            clientSecret: 'bbb',
            token: mApiGetToken()
}

mApiSettings.uriGetToken = 'https://ccc/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=' + encodeURIComponent( mApiSettings.clientId ) + '&client_secret=' + encodeURIComponent( mApiSettings.clientSecret );
```

Comment: "Anyway your code should work if you change…" — No, it shouldn't. It will give `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientId' of undefined` because the object literal isn't assigned to `mApiSettings` until it has been created.