# javascript variable equal to value from function

Tags: javascript, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to return AJAX response Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225667/how-to-return-ajax-response-text)
>   [How to return the response from an AJAX call from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call-from-a-function)

So I have a javascript function where I'm doing an AJAX call to see if the user is online or offline. It looks something like this.

```
function onlineStatus(){

    $.ajax({
        url: "assets/ajax/online-offline.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
          return html;
        }
    }); 
}
```

I would like to assign the value from this function as a variable that I can then use.

Something like this.

```
var test = onlineStatus();

if (test == "true")
   alert("online");
else
   alert("offline");
```

Is this possible? I must be doing something wrong, but can't figure out how to achieve this result. Thanks

// Edit:
Thanks for your help everyone, sorry, didn't realize it may have been a duplicate question. I wasn't sure what to search for initially, so I didn't see anything related.

Comment: You cannot directly do this because AJAX is asynchronous by default. Either you have to specify the `async: false` option to `$.ajax` or you need another way of doing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$.ajax` is asynchronous so you can't return anything from `onlineStatus`, you need to pass it a callback function that can be called when the ajax call completes.

```
function onlineStatus(callback){

    $.ajax({
        url: "assets/ajax/online-offline.php",
        cache: false,
        success: callback
    }); 
}

onlineStatus(function(test) {
    if (test == "true")
       alert("online");
    else
       alert("offline");
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Since calls happen asynchronously, you'll have to pass a callback function into `onlineStatus`.  Something like:

```
function onlineStatus(callback){

    $.ajax({
        url: "assets/ajax/online-offline.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
          callback(html);
        }
    }); 
}
```

And then call it with:

```
onlineStatus(function (html)
   {
      // Do stuff with the status
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

AJAX is *asynchronous*, that's what the A stands for. You need pass a callback.

For example:

```
function onlineStatus(callback){

    $.ajax({
        url: "assets/ajax/online-offline.php",
        cache: false,
        success: callback
    }); 
}

onlineStatus(function(data) { 
    if (data == "true") { 
        alert "online"; 
    }
    else {
        alert "offline";
    }
}
```

Comment: @MikeChristensen: Thanks. A simple typo, now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can simple use a deferred object.

```
function onlineStatus(){

    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "assets/ajax/online-offline.php",
        cache: false
    }); 

    return request;
}



var test = onlineStatus();
test.done(function(html) {
    if (html)
       alert("online");
    else
       alert("offline");
});
```

`$.ajax` returns a `jqXHR`, so you can use `.done`:

`jqXHR.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {});`

`An alternative construct to the success callback option, the .done() method replaces the deprecated`

Answer (score 0):

The `$.ajax` method is asynchronous so you need to handle its return values in the callback.

```
function onlineStatus(){

    $.ajax({
        url: "assets/ajax/online-offline.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            if (html == "true")
                alert("online");
            else
                alert("offline");
        }
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this.......but it is not a good method because synchronous request by ajax makes your code slow.......

```
function onlineStatus(){
var data;
    $.ajax({
        url: "assets/ajax/online-offline.php",
        cache: false,
        async:false,
        success: function(html){
           data = html;
        }
    }); 

return data;
}
```

or 
if you only want to dispaly the alert box then...

```
function onlineStatus(){

    $.ajax({
        url: "assets/ajax/online-offline.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
           if (html== "true")
            alert("online");
            else
            alert("offline");
        }
    }); 

return data;
}
```

Comment: Weird, never knew jQuery had a synchronous mode..  That's asking for trouble.

Comment: due to async= false, "data" would get true/false from the "html" so function would as a result returns it...."synchronously"

Answer (score 0):

jQuery ajax call is an asynchronous call. You will have to wait to get the results before you can use them for showing the alert.

```
    var isOnline = false;
    checkOnlineStatus();

    function checkOnlineStatus(){

        $.ajax({
            url: "assets/ajax/online-offline.php",
            cache: false,
            success: callback
            }
        }); 

    }
    function callback(html){
        isOnline = (html == "online");
        showAlert();
    }
    function showAlert(){
        if (isOnline == "true")
           alert("online");
        else
           alert("offline");
    }
```