# Getting undefined from ajax request

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to return AJAX response Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225667/how-to-return-ajax-response-text)
>   [How to return the response from an AJAX call from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call-from-a-function)

I am trying to get a record from SQL according to the value I send with ajax. But all I get is undefined when I console.log it.

jQuery:

```
function extraOptions(str){
    $.get("inc/ajax/extra_options.php",
        {q:str},
        function(html){
           return html;
        }
    );
}

$("#auto_model").change(function(){
   console.log(extraOptions(this.value));
});
```

extra_options.php:

```
$q = $_GET['q'];

echo extra_options($mysqli, $q);
```

extra_options function:

```
function extra_options($mysqli, $q){
    $query = "SELECT
                                extra_options
                            FROM
                                vozila_tbl
                            WHERE
                                Model_vozila = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($q)."'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    return $row['extra_options'];
}
```

Edit:

It should return 1 or 0 and if it returns 0 I want to change the updateField function with an if statement.

```
function updateField(str, id, prevvalue, value, vehicletype){
    $.get("inc/ajax/form_rest.php",
        {q:str, prevvalue:prevvalue, value:value, vehicletype:vehicletype},
        function(html){
           $('#'+id).html(html);
        }
    );
}

$("#auto_model").change(function(){
   updateField(this.value, 'auto_bodywork', 3, 4, this.parentNode.id), resetBelow(2,'auto'), show('auto_bodywork');
});
```

The line I need to change in the if statement is:

```
updateField(this.value, 'auto_bodywork', 3, 4, this.parentNode.id), resetBelow(2,'auto'), show('auto_bodywork');
```

Comment: How do I make it return what I sent with PHP?

Comment: Your ajax call returns 1 or 0 as `html`?

Comment: Depends on the value. If extra_options is set to 1 it returns 1. It is about a select menu which returns the value as q in the where statement of my php function. If it returns 1 I want it to return more select fields. Just like on this website: http://www.onderdelenzoeker.nl/ when you choose 2011>Renault>Master for example

Comment: Okay, one second let me re-read this a 20th time.

Comment: I wanted to check it with console.log if it returns 1. I did not try out without console.log yet. Would extraOptions(this.value) == 1 be true the way I have it now? Sorry for confusing you

Comment: The `extraOptions` function doesn't return a value of any kind. So, it will always be `== undefined`. AJAX is asynchronous. You might want to lookup what that means. I'm still unclear on what exactly you are trying to accomplish with these functions. You are binding two different functions to the same event on the same object - I'm not sure how they are supposed to relate.

Comment: Ive been working on this problem for days now but cant figure it out. I thought that maybe if I call this function first it would react on the if statement in the next function.. I just wanted this function to give a variable with the return in it

Comment: I updated my answer with my best guess at what you are attempting to do. I think your main problem is that you don't understand what `asynchronous` means, or how it acts. It doesn't block execution until it returns. It returns immediately, and calls the callback when it receives a response from your AJAX call - whenever that may be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `return` statement is returning from the anonymous function, not from `extraOptions()`. Thus, `extraOptions()` returns undefined because it is returning nothing.

Try this instead:

```
function extraOptions(str){
    $.get("inc/ajax/extra_options.php",
        {q:str},
        function(html){
           console.log(html);
        }
    );
}

$("#auto_model").change(function(){
   extraOptions(this.value);
});
```

If I understand you right, the following code should do what you want:

```
$("#auto_model").change(function(e) {
    extraOptions(this.value, this.parentNode.id);
});

function extraOptions(str, parentNodeId) {        
    $.get("inc/ajax/extra_options.php",
        {q:str},
        function(data) {
            if (data == "1") {
                updateField(str, "auto_bodywork", 3, 4, parentNodeId);
            } else if (data == "0") {
                updateField(str, "auto_type", 5, 7, parentNodeId);
            } else {
                //Not 0 or 1.
            }

            resetBelow(2, "auto");
            show("auto_bodywork");
        }
    );
}

function updateField(str, id, prevvalue, value, vehicletype){
    $.get("inc/ajax/form_rest.php",
        {q:str, prevvalue:prevvalue, value:value, vehicletype:vehicletype},
        function(html){
           $('#'+id).html(html);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: I will edit my question to explain my question better

Comment: I editted it. Its kinda complicated and I have tried getting an answer to this earlier without even this if statement idea but I didnt get response from anyone

Comment: That seems like its getting close but I want the updateField() function inside the extraOptions() function to change according to the response of the ajax return. For example if it returns 1 I want it to be updateField(str, "auto_bodywork", 3, 4, parentNodeId); and if it returns 0 I want it to be updateField(str, "auto_type", 5, 7, parentNodeId);

Comment: Updated with if statement.

Comment: Awesome thank you I think that should work! You are a life saver!

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to look-up asynchronous (That's the A in AJAX btw), and how it performs differently than the thread-blocking procedural code you are used too.

Comment: I will look it up but unfortunately it gives me the error "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"..

Comment: Try again. I'm heading home. Will check again when I get there.

Comment: Alright thank you, I am trying stuff out

Comment: The error is about this this.parentNode.id "this.parentNode" = undefined and id is the property that cant be read.

Comment: Oh im really sorry I didnt update the last edit. That was the problem it works prefectly now thanks a lot!!!!