# JavaScript function to return AJAX response (no jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need a pure JavaScript function (Sorry, no jQuery) that will return the response from a successful AJAX call. Here's the function I've got so far, I want to return the `HTMLobject` with the HTML from the response:

```
function getHtml(url) {
    var httpRequest;
    var HTMLobject;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {}
        }
    }

    if (!httpRequest) {
        console.error('Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
        return false;
    }

    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
            if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
                // OK, turn the string into HTML.
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.innerHTML = httpRequest.responseText;
                // Assign the converted HTML to HTMLobject.
                HTMLobject = div.childNodes[0];
            } else {
                console.debug('There was a problem with the request.');
            }
        }
    };

    httpRequest.open('GET', url);
    httpRequest.send();

    return HTMLobject;
}
```

I know *why*, `HTMLobject` returns undefined, but I need it to work. Is there a way to have the function return the object after the AJAX has completed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return AJAX response Text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225667/how-to-return-ajax-response-text)

Comment: @Quentin I didn't want to use any libraries.

Comment: The principles are the same whether you use a library or not.

Comment: Up-voted simply because you're trying to do it without a framework. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the solution is such a case is to use a callback function.

Ex:

```
function getHtml(url, callback) {
    ....
    ....
    callback(HTMLobject); //instead of returning the HTMLobject, call a callback function as pass the `HTMLobject` as a argument.
}
```

Usage:

```
getHtml('url', function(HTMLobject){
    //Do something with HTMLobject
});
```

instead of

```
var HTMLobject = getHtml('url');
//Do something with HTMLobject
```

*Making a request `async: false` is a bad idea since it will block the page till the request is completed(UI will not get redrawn and ui interaction will not happen)*.

Comment: Aah, of course. Thanks for explaining about the synchronous option too, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

make request synchronous , just by doing as below

```
httpRequest.open('GET', url,false);//false make request synchronous 
 httpRequest.send();
```

The "false" option says the call is synchronous, meaning that the code will hang until a response comes back

Comment: This can produce unintended consequences like freezing up the UI on the page until the response returns, which in the case of a glitch or problem with the server or connection, could be a long time.