# Javascript Simple Reusable Ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I' am trying to make a simple reusable ajax function. After spending hours on Google and and trying myself I have no option but to ask for help.

I' am getting "undefined" alert from the Javascript. It works fine when I don't use the function method. Below is the code for it...

```
    $("#formloginadmin").submit(function (){
        var url = "ajax/ajax_login_admin.php";
        var txtemail    = $("#txtemail").val();
        var txtpass     = $("#txtpass").val();
        var formdata    = $('#formloginadmin').serialize();
        var revel       = true;

        txtemail            = $.trim(txtemail);
        txtpass             = $.trim(txtpass);

        response            = ajax_post(url, formdata);
        alert(response);
        return false;
    });                                     

function ajax_post(url, formdata){
    $.post(url, formdata, function (data){
        return data;
    });
}
```

Comment: Is this your first ever ajax code or you have done some ajax calls before?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return AJAX response Text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225667/how-to-return-ajax-response-text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Correct way is this**

> ajax_post(url, formdata).done(function(response) {
>       alert(response); });

The way you are accessing the response of the ajax request is not correct. Look into this link:
[jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example)

Hope you got the idea.

And for your question why you are getting `undefined`:

`response            = ajax_post(url, formdata);` of yours is a ajax call and so the execution of next line `alert(response);` occurs before the return of that ajax call. Because the call `ajax_post` is asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ajax_post(url, formdata){
    $.post(url, formdata, function (data){
        return data;
    });
}
```

This is a function which calls `$.post` inside. That `$.post` is an asynchronous function, meaning it won’t return its result but will notify you later that the result is there. That’s what the callback function does. In your callback function, the inner-most function, you get the `data` as the parameter and return it from the callback function.

So somewhere in the asynchronous timeline, there is a function that returns something to a function which is no longer executed. So this won’t work.

Asynchronous functions are made to return immediately and give you a notice of the result later. So you cannot *return* the data just like that in a synchronous matter. Instaed you really need to use the asynchronous pattern and use callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already said, `$.post` is *asynchronous*, meaning you can't get a return value from it.

What you can do, is return a [*promise*](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) to send back a return value *later*.  Handily, the return value of `$.post` is just such a promise:

```
function ajax_post(url, formdata){
    return $.post(url, formdata);
}
```

(Note however that you now have a function that does nothing but call `$.post` with those same parameters!)

Once you've got the promise you can then trigger a callback when that promise is *resolved*:

```
ajax_post(url, formdata).done(function(response) {
    alert(response);
});
```