# Can't save information from getJSON into var

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Could anyone explain to me why the following is happening. First of all see my code below. Trying to get data via a JSON request and save it for later use.

```
        var entities;

        //@jsonGetEntities is an url build by asp.net MVC and this works
        $.getJSON("@jsonGetEntities", function(getdata) {
            entities = getdata;

            //I would expect that this is the first alert
            alert(entities + "first");
        });            

        //I would expect that this is the second alert
        alert(entities + "second");
```

However, the alert that I would expect to be first comes second and `entities` is actually filled.

In the last alert `entities` is not filled.

I can't seem to understand why my json is not saved to the var and why an alert that is called later is executed earlier? Could you also give me a possible other solution?

Comment: Yet another duplicate of [How to return AJAX response Text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225667/how-to-return-ajax-response-text)

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate, I don't even use prototype. Thanks for the tip though. The answers there can come in handy.

Comment: It's Ajax. The problem is the same. The solution is the same. The syntax is very slightly different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because [`getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) is **asynchronous**.

The *first alert* is inside the success callback of getJSON which gets executed asynchronously once the server returns.

The *second alert* however, runs immediately after triggering the AJAX request (via `getJSON()`)

Comment: Ok fair enough, can I force it to wait somehow?

Comment: @NickN. make an ajax request and set async false

Comment: Well, you can. But you shouldn't.

Comment: but how can I use the data got with `getJSON` later?

Comment: @NickN. Please see the following references: [jQuery Deferred Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) and [jQuery Callbacks](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/). These may be able to help you.

Comment: For the best user experience, I advice you to read the above links (posted by War10ck) and then design your application around callbacks.

Comment: I can't seem to get it working with my syntax, should I use another?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.getJSON("@jsonGetEntities", function(getdata) {
            entities = getdata;

            //I would expect that this is the first alert
            alert(entities + "first");
            setTimeout(function() {
               //I would expect that this is the second alert
               alert(entities + "second");
            },2000); // wait 2 sec.
        });
```

Comment: Why would you wait to execute the second alert?

Comment: And how can you be sure it'll be done in 2000 ms! And why is the second alert inside the callback? The whole point was about how he can use it *outside*..

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense, I am not going to wait for a random number of seconds. That doesn't seem like a clean solution. Thanks though.