# AJAX XMLHttpRequest error

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have this basic "GET" request on a demo page I'm building via localhost.
Both json and html file are in the same folder.

```
http://localhost.com/test.html
http://localhost.com/myList.json
```

Unfortunately when making the request I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: results is not defined.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

My html is as follows.

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function get_json_request() {
        var httpRequest;
        httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httpRequest.open("GET", "myList.json", true);
        httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json", true);
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (httpRequest.readyState === 4 && httpRequest.status === 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
                var results = document.getElementById("results");
                results.innerHTML = data.user;
            } else {
                alert('There was a problem with the request.');
                }
            }
        httpRequest.send(null); 
        results.innerHTML = "Processing....";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id"results"></div> 
    <script type="text/javascript">get_json_request();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Typo `<div id"results">`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return AJAX response Text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225667/how-to-return-ajax-response-text)

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the reference to "results" in a conditional statement. If that variable is not initialised, it will naturally return null.

Comment: That's a potential second problem. The first problem is that Ajax is asynchronous.

Comment: See the earlier vote to close as duplicate with associated comment on the question itself.