# Javascript ajax returns undefined

Tags: php, javascript, html

This functions always returns undefined but the alert is showing the right value.

```
    function _gesamt()
{
   var link = "speichern.php?gesamt=true";
    //alert(link);
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = function(){
        //alert("Ready:"+req.readyState);
        if(req.readyState == 4){
            alert(req.responseText);
            return req.responseText;
        }
    }
    req.open("GET",link,false);
    req.send();
}
```

Comment: Thats because its run asynchronously.

Comment: Yet another duplicate (among hundreds) of [How to return AJAX response Text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225667/how-to-return-ajax-response-text)

Comment: But if I change the false to true it still returns undefined..

Comment: `function _gesamt` doesn't have a return statement so it will always return `undefined`, but see the duplicate for the right way to handle this.

Comment: Is return req.responseText; no return statement?

Comment: @LiamSchnell — It is, but it is in a different function.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX is asynchronous. So you must use callbacks.

```
function _gesamt(callback)
{
   var link = "speichern.php?gesamt=true";
    //alert(link);
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = function(){
        //alert("Ready:"+req.readyState);
        if(req.readyState == 4){
            callback(req.responseText);
        }
    }
    req.open("GET",link,false);
    req.send();
}

_gesamt(function(response) {
    // do your work here
    alert(response);
});
```

Comment: Well, If I just c/p it it is still not running properly. Here is the rest of the code

[code]_bp_iframe.default_amount   = _gesamt();    /* Donation-amount, integer 1-99 */ [/code]

Answer (score 0):

The `return` is inside the inner function, so running `_gesamt` is not supposed to return anything (even setting aside the question of why you would want to issue AJAX requests this way)