# access json object returned from php file via ajax

Tags: ajax, json

```
$(function() {

    var sineData;

    $.ajax({
        url : '../_php/loadFromDB.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : 'getSines',
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            sineData=result; 
        },
        error : function () {
           alert("error");
        }
    })

});
```

Under Console->All->Response in firebug I get the below as expected:

`[{"userID":"1","email":"user@mail.com","number":"800.256.6547","ext":"5788","startDay":"Sunday","endDay":"Thursday"}]`

but when I look at `sineData` it is Undefined.

I want to be able to access these values like  `sineData[0].email`

Where am I going wrong?

---

`async: false,`  ended up fixing this for me but probably isnt the best solution for most aplications.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return AJAX response Text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225667/how-to-return-ajax-response-text)

Comment: are you accessing `sineData` outside the `success` function?

Comment: @Khanh TO , Id like to yes. I was under the impression I could do that by decalring the var at the top and assigining it a value in `success`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably accessing sineData outside the ajax call. You  are trying to access it before the asynchronous call is done. Try this:

```
function whenIsDone(result){
  // Do whatever you want with the variable result
  console.log(result[0].email);
}
    $.ajax({
        url : '../_php/loadFromDB.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : 'getSines',
        dataType : 'json',
        success : whenIsDone,
        error : function () {
           alert("error");
      }
  })
```

Comment: still getting undefined, and no log. Why wouldnt it be whenIsDone(result) here BTW? (tried that to but of course that didnt work)

Comment: "You are trying to access it before the asynchronous call is done." that got me thinking, adding `async: false,` makes my original code work. The object I will be returnin will only ever be 10-15 rows long so I dont think not being asynchronous will be an issue, right?

Comment: Could you post the complete non-working-code on jsfiddle.net ?