# jQuery cross-domain request returns 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, cross-domain

After reading various examples on stackoverflow I wrote this function :

```
function showGetResult(crossDomainUrl) {
    $.ajax({
        url: crossDomainUrl,
        type : 'GET',
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (data) {
            debug(data);
            return data;
        }
    });
}
```

and called it using this

```
alert(showGetResult(crossDomainUrl));
```

But all I get is '`undefined`', this is being used in a web-browser extension inside a content-script.

Comment: exact duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return AJAX response Text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225667/how-to-return-ajax-response-text)

Comment: Although similar both does not address my problem like numerous other examples here, see my comment - "Thanks this works, but I need to grab a javascript file. I tried the datatype values jsonp, script and html and all failed. see - jsfiddle.net/tsyGj"

Comment: @Stacked — You have two different problems. The question this is marked as a duplicate of solves the problem of returning the data. Your other problem (which we can only tell from your JSFiddle, and not from any code in your question) is the Same Origin Policy, and that is covered by [this other duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy).

Comment: @Quentin Should I delete this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the Ajax request runs asynchronously. The `return data` doesn't do anything. You could change it to (updated to reflect the request in the comments to be able to download a script):

```
function showGetResult(crossDomainUrl) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: crossDomainUrl,
        type : 'GET',
        dataType: 'script',
        crossDomain: true
     });
}

showGetResult('http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js')
    .done(function(data) {
        alert("success: " + data);
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, ex) {
        alert("failed: " + textStatus);
    });
```

For the call actually to work cross-domain, you will need to use jsonp or script. Read this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) for more information about Same-origin policy. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3506208/932282) for more information about using jsonp.

The code above will **inject** the downloaded jscript in the dom **and execute** it.

Comment: I tested this in my code but no alert is getting fired, same with http://jsfiddle.net/UmxRr/ ?

Comment: As in your original code, only success was handled. I've added the fail handler, see http://jsfiddle.net/UmxRr/2/

Comment: But why is it failing in the first place ?

Comment: Updated the answer for downloading scripts, as you requested.

Comment: still gives ```success: undefined```.

Comment: That's correct. No value is returned, but "The code above will inject the downloaded jscript in the dom and execute it."

Comment: jQuery doesn't use Ajax for downloading cross-domain scripts. It injects a `<script src=...>` tag in the header and let the browser handle it. You could check (after a few seconds) for the script tag with the src attribute and use those contents (won't work in jsfiddle): `var data = $("script[src^='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js']").text();`

Answer (score -1):

The `$.ajax()` set up the query, and return immediately, so the function returns before the request is completed. Specify a function to call on completion of the query using `success`.

```
function showGetResult(crossDomainUrl) {
    $.ajax({
        url: crossDomainUrl,
        type : 'GET',
        crossDomain: true,
        success: showData
    });
}

function showData(data){
    debug(data);
    return data;
}
showGetResult(crossDomainUrl);
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/5J66u/8/ - (updated to specify jsonp and a better URL for it)

Comment: Thanks this works, but I need to grab a javascript file. I tried the datatype values jsonp, script and html and all failed. see - http://jsfiddle.net/tsyGj/

Comment: The `showGetResult` function will still return `undefined`, it doesn't matter that `showData` returns.