# Jquery form validation with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

i need to check if username exist. If it exist, I increment a variable "form_error".
If "form_errors" is > 0, then i stop code with return false.

But, when i make an Ajax call, i cannot increment this variable. Probably is it a scope / visibility problem?

So, in the case that i have an error on username, my form_errors will be forever 0 and form is submit...

How i can increment that form_errors?

Thank you to all, I leave a piece of code

```
$('#add-sponsor').submit(function() {
var form_errors = 0;
var username = ('#username').val();
$.ajax({
        url         :   location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/commands.php?action=check-username',
        data        :   {
                            username    : username
                        },
        type        :   'post'
    }).done(function (result) {
        if (result=='false') {
            $('#username').parent().addClass('has-error');
            $('#username').parent().removeClass('has-success');
            $('#username').parent().next('.help-block').text('Questo username già esiste');
            form_errors++;
        } else {
            $('#username').parent().addClass('has-success');
            $('#username').parent().removeClass('has-error');
            $('#username').parent().next('.help-block').text('');
        }
    }); // ajax


if (form_errors > 0) {
    return false;
}

console.log(form_errors); // <- this is forever 0
}
```

Comment: this would be forever 0 because you use `return false` before it, if errors > 0. It would be better if you debug in your browser what result is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return AJAX response Text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225667/how-to-return-ajax-response-text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$.ajax function is asynchronous so will continue execution of

```
if (form_errors > 0) {
    return false;
}
```

before the done function is executed.

Comment: In effect, add "async: false" did the trick. I made an error during copy and paste, changing last piece of code. Of course first i check if there are errors, console.log them and AFTER i "return false". This was only a typo error :) Thank you for the indication of "async" ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (form_errors > 0) {
    return false;
}

console.log(form_errors); // <- this is forever 0
```

You check here if you have errors, and if so, you return...so, the console.log will never be hit, unless you have no errors. Maybe just use...

```
if (form_errors > 0) {
    console.log(form_errors);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet might be to use some sort of variable outside your submit function
eg

```
var isValid = false;
$('#add-sponsor').submit(function() {
    if(!isValid)
    {
        var form_errors = 0;
        var username = ('#username').val();
        $.ajax({
                url         :   location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/commands.php?action=check-username',
                data        :   { username    : username },
                type        :   'post'
        }).done(function (result) {
            if (result=='false') {
                $('#username').parent().addClass('has-error');
                $('#username').parent().removeClass('has-success');
                $('#username').parent().next('.help-block').text('Questo username già esiste');
                isValid = false;
                $('#add-sponsor').submit();
            } else {
                $('#username').parent().addClass('has-success');
                $('#username').parent().removeClass('has-error');
                $('#username').parent().next('.help-block').text('');
                isValid = true;
                $('#add-sponsor').submit();
            }
        }); // ajax

        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considered using the [jQuery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)? You could set up your form using a remote validation rule to check whether the username ist valid. jQuery validation let's you implement your callbacks within the [submitHandler](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate) or the invalidHandler.

Try this code if you want to test it. Just make sure to include the jquery.validate.js as well as additional-methods.js into your page.

```
var validator = jQuery("the-sponsor-form").validate({
    messages: {
        username: {
            remote: 'Questo username già esiste'
        }
    },
    rules: {
        username: {
            required: true,
            remote: {
                url: location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/commands.php?action=check-username',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    username: $('#username').val();
                }
            }
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        alert("now submit the form");
        jQuery(form).submit();
    }
});
```