# read text file google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have got a text file representing a wireless signal survey. It consists of lines each composed of a longitude, a latitude and the wireless signal strength in that location. I'm trying to read this file via Javascript then extract locations and mark them on Google Maps. I managed to read the text file but the text within fails to be returned outside the function to be used for the map. I'd appreciate any help, thanks in advance. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
  }
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var textlines;

function processFile(fileContent) {
var lines= fileContent.split('\n');
return lines;
}

function loadFile(uri) {
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
r.open('GET', uri, true);
r.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (r.readyState == 4) {
textlines =  processFile(r.responseText);
}
}
r.send(null);
return textlines;
}

function initialize() {
// Create the map.
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 16,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.623169,32.269097),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);
var line=loadFile('ss.txt');
/*setTimeout(function(){
// alert(textlines);
},100);*/
var citymap = {};
setTimeout(function(){
for (var i=0;i<line.length;i++)
{ 
var newline=line[i];
var segments=newline.split('\t');
var dbm=segments[0];
var lat=segments[2];
var lang=segments[1];
citymap[i] = {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lang)
};
}
},4000);
var cityCircle;
// Construct the circle for each value in citymap.
// Note: We scale the population by a factor of 20.
 for (var i in citymap) {
 var populationOptions = {
   strokeColor: '#FF0000',
   strokeOpacity: 0.8,
   strokeWeight: 2,
   fillColor: '#FF0000',
   fillOpacity: 0.35,
   map: map,
   center: citymap[i].center,
   radius: 280
 };
 // Add the circle for this city to the map.
 cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
}
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script> 
</head>
<body>
 <div id="map-canvas"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you have return correct code but your variable that return values should be declare publicly initialize first.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've already tried that but in vain. the variable textlines is already global and is returned into the variable line. I've tried using both of them but neither of them works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are making an asynchronous call to load the text file, but treating it as if it were synchronous.

You can't just stuff the result into a global variable. That doesn't help, because it's not the *visibility* of the variable that's causing trouble, it's the *timing*.

What you have to do instead is load the data file and then *call* a function that will use that data.

Also it would help a lot to use consistent and proper indentation so the code is more readable.

And finally, I took the liberty of simplifying the code a bit. So it looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
  }
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>

function initialize() {
    loadFile('ss.txt');
}

function loadFile(uri) {
    var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
    r.open('GET', uri, true);
    r.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (r.readyState == 4) {
            var lines = r.responseText.split('\n');
            loadMap(lines);
        }
    }
    r.send(null);
}

function loadMap(lines) {
    // Create the map.
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.623169,32.269097),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions
    );
    for( var i = 0;  i < lines.length; i++ ) { 
        var segments = lines[i].split('\t');
        var dbm = segments[0];
        var lat = segments[2];
        var lng = segments[1];

        // Construct the circle for each value in citymap.
        // Note: We scale the population by a factor of 20.
        var populationOptions = {
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            map: map,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
            radius: 280
        };
        // Add the circle for this city to the map.
        var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for replying. I got your point and thanks for simplifying things but your code didn't work. When I debug the code it doesn't get into if(readyState==4) and then it just stops. Thanks a lot for your help but I'll really appreciate a bit more help concerning this problem.

Comment: please provide the contents of your ss.txt

Comment: I wouldn't know about the XHR problem off the top of my head. I would just use jQuery and `$.get()` to simplify that part and get on to the rest.