# How to return values from $.get

Tags: ajax, html, jquery

Tried to read text from a local text file using jquery but if want to return a value from $.get, its not working. So I trie it like this

```
 function read() {
        var result=0;
            $.get("version.txt?_ts=" + new Date().getTime(), function (data) {
                var y1 = parseInt(data[0]);
                var y2 = parseInt(data[1]);
                var y = (y1 * 10) + y2;
                result=y;
            });
         return result;
        }

        function drr() {
            var d = read();
            document.write(d);
        }
```

but result value is remaining 0. could someone helpme with this

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: what is the difference between this and your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20514183/function-not-returning-value-to-other-function)

Comment: I want that data to be used to draw a graph. so I need it to be stored in a variable, in that function

Answer (score 1):

as `$.get` is similar as `$.ajax`, you might want to be looking into something I've done before.

I used to have the following code to return a value from an `$.ajax` request, but translated to your `$.get`.

```
function read (callback) {
    $.get("version.txt?_ts=" + new Date().getTime(), function (data) {
        var y1 = parseInt(data[0]);
        var y2 = parseInt(data[1]);
        var y = (y1 * 10) + y2;
        return callback(y);
    });
}

function readVersion () {
    read(function (result) { 
        console.log(result);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function read() {
        var result=0;
            $.get("version.txt?_ts=" + new Date().getTime(), function (data) {
                var y1 = parseInt(data[0]);
                var y2 = parseInt(data[1]);
                var y = (y1 * 10) + y2;
                return y;
            });
        }

        function drr() {
            var d = read();
            document.write(d);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To read local files you need to use the HTML5 File API. No matter how your JS/jQuery/AJAX looks like...

[Check out the API here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)