# How to return bool (true or false ) in java script ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have tried with this code. But it is not working. I just need to return state of bool value. But always this returns `true`.

```
function nic_is_exist(){

  var state = true;
  var nic = document.getElementById("tbNic").value;
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }else{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  } 
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 1){
      document.getElementById("spNic").innerHTML="<img src='../Style/images/loarding.gif' />";  
    }     
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
      document.getElementById("spNic").innerHTML="";
      var str = xmlhttp.responseText;
      alert(str+2);
      if( str != "1"){
        alert("if");
        fill_form(str);
        checkNull();
        state = true;   
      }else{
        alert("else");
        state = false;
      }       
    }     
  }
  xmlhttp.open("POST","rpoRegister_PHP.php?a="+nic,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  return state;
}
```

Comment: Where is your php code

Comment: Also explain what "not working" means.

Comment: because you have initialized var state = true; as true, just use var state; and see

Comment: What are you returning as string in the AJAX callback?

Comment: By the time, ajax returns with result and make your state true/false, your 'nic_is_exist' function return state which is initialized to true. Hence, it always return true.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return AJAX response Text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225667/how-to-return-ajax-response-text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX is asynchronous.  If you need to do something based on the TRUE/FALSE then you need to put it within your `if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)` block.  Or replace your `state = true;` and `state = false;` code with a function call.

Example:

```
if( str != "1"){
    alert("if");
    fill_form(str);
    checkNull();
    doSuccessCode(); 
  }else{
    alert("else");
    doFailCode();
  }
```

Comment: `function setState(s){
 ajaxState = s; //ajaxState is a globle veriable
 alert("setState -> "+ajaxState);
}` but not working

Answer (score 0):

your ajax request run Asynchronous so before your ajax request complete your function return your `state` variable value which is `true` during initialize

You should move whatever you need to do with that return value into the function itself.

There are basically two ways how to solve this:

1. Make the AJAX call synchronous (lets call it SJAX).
2. Restructure your code to work properly with callbacks.

Comment: can u post a example .. @rajesh

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Answer (score 0):

depends on how you echo responseText from rpoRegister_PHP.php
have you try to use .trim() before you compare them? It might be an extra space.

```
  var str = xmlhttp.responseText.trim();
  alert(str+2);
  if( str != "1"){
    alert("if");
    fill_form(str);
    checkNull();
    state = true;   
  }else{
    alert("else");
    state = false;
  }
```