# Passing data outside ajax call, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vimeo

I'm getting vimeo thumbnails from the API and I'm using a jQuery function to append the data to the dom.

I'm trying to access **thumb_url** outside ajax, so I can return it to jQuery, but it doesn't work.

```
function getThumb(vimeoVideoID) {
var thumb_url;

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/' + vimeoVideoID + '.json',
    jsonp: 'callback',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data[0].thumbnail_large);
        thumb_url = data[0].thumbnail_large;
    }
});
return thumb_url;
}

$('.video').each(function () {
var thumb_url = getThumb(this.id);
$(this).append('<img src="' + thumb_url + '" class="video_preview"/>');

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gyQS4/2/
help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return AJAX response Text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225667/how-to-return-ajax-response-text)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because AJAX calls are **asynchronous**, you cannot return and access **thumb_url** the way that you're trying to.

In other words, because your AJAX call can get **data** at any time (it could take 1 second; it could take 10 seconds), the rest of the code (including the *return* statement) will execute synchronously, i.e. before the server even has a chance to respond with **data**.

A common design solution used in these situations is to execute whatever you want to execute inside of a *callback function*.

You could do something similar to this:

```
success: function (data) {
    console.log(data[0].thumbnail_large);
    thumb_url = data[0].thumbnail_large;

    //utilize your callback function
    doSomething(thumb_url);
}

/*     then, somewhere else in the code      */

//this is your callback function
function doSomething(param) {

    //do something with your parameter
    console.log(param);

}
```

Comment: or like that, using done() method of promise interface: http://jsfiddle.net/xSKc8/

Comment: It logs the actualy image, but when I inspect the dom, I still get img src="undefined" .  Still looks like var thumb_url has not been returned in the end http://jsfiddle.net/gyQS4/3/

Comment: You can't use a return statement here.  You have to do everything inside the callback function.  [See this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gyQS4/4/)